# Laravel SQLSTATE[HY000] [1049] Unknown database + PHP artisan migrate

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-migrations

I have setup Laravel before and I have never encountered a Database unknown issue. I am trying to install the default Laravel migration on a new project.

I have already created the database on my server.

I am using MAMP Apache port:80 MYSQL Port: 3306

My env setup looks like this:

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=thevinesa
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=******
```

When I try to use PHP artisan migrate; I get an error of database unknown

```
SQLSTATE[HY000] [1049] Unknown database 'thevinesa' (SQL: select * from information_schema.tables where table_schema = thevinesa and table_name = migrations and table_type = 'BASE TABLE') at vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php:703
        699▕         // If an exception occurs when attempting to run a query, we'll format the error
        700▕         // message to include the bindings with SQL, which will make this exception a
        701▕         // lot more helpful to the developer instead of just the database's errors.
        702▕         catch (Exception $e) {
        703▕             throw new QueryException(
        704▕                 $query, $this->prepareBindings($bindings), $e
        705▕             );
        706▕         }
        707▕     }
    
          +33 vendor frames 
      34  artisan:37
          Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel::handle(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
```

How can I solve this error

Comment: Have you definitely created the `thevinesa` database i.e. ran `CREATE DATABASE thevinesa;`?

Comment: Never ever share your password, even if it's just a localhost database. Are you sure you have typed in the database correctly, in a case-sensitive manner? Is the port correct? Is the username and password correct? Can you connect to the database via CLI?

Comment: with sequal pro, i can connect to the database but through laravel, I am unable

Comment: @ThandoHlophe can you check my answer and the post error log here so i can help.

Answer (score 2):

**Step 1:**

Fire this command inside your project

```
php artisan optimize:clear
```

**Step 2:**

Then start project if in local:

```
php artisan serve
```

Database is then connected.

Comment: Hi Ali, I can run the  php artisan serve, but the issue is when I try to use PHP artisan migrate, I am unable add the migration to the database

Comment: Have you run the first command ? Before that run step 1 ===> then start again php artrisan serve ===> after that you can check for php artisan migrate

Comment: I followed your steps but im still not getting the SQLSTATE[HY000] [1049] Unknown database 'thevinesa'

I've build a Laravel project.

Comment: can i see the code what you want to migrate

Comment: I found the issue, so my ~bash directory had the incorrect $PATH, I updated the $PATH and I was able to sort out the issue

Answer (score 1):

**Suggestion from @ThandoHlophe**

*

### I found the issue, so my ~bash directory had the incorrect $PATH, I updated the $PATH and I was able to sort out the issue

- 

It's an simple error, you still did't created your database in mysql or phpmyadmin named `thevinesa`

```
DB_DATABASE=thevinesa
```

Laravel try to find out the database name `thevinesa` to connect but they didn't find and database named `thevinesa` . Try to create database.
Then migrate.

```
php artisan cache:clear
php artisan config:clear

php artisan migrate
```

**command related to database**

```
  migrate:fresh        Drop all tables and re-run all migrations


migrate:install      Create the migration repository
  migrate:refresh      Reset and re-run all migrations
  migrate:reset        Rollback all database migrations
  migrate:rollback     Rollback the last database migration
  migrate:status       Show the status of each migratioin
```

**Or**

Laravel can't connect to your database.

Go to `Storage->logs->laravel.log` file you will find your error

or you can use `php artisan migrate -v` if you are in `linux` . It will show the error details.

And did you create that database?

Check if you have a file `bootstrap\cache\config.php`. If so remove it.

I didn't find any pdoException Error but If you changed the

```
`config->database.php`   file
```

Here is my `config->databse.php` try to compare these
This code taken from **Laravel Framework 7.30.4**, It might be different but you can have a basic idea.

```html
'mysql' => [
            'driver' => 'mysql',
            'url' => env('DATABASE_URL'),
            'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
            'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
            'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
            'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
            'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
            'prefix' => '',
            'prefix_indexes' => true,
            'strict' => true,
            'engine' => null,
            'options' => extension_loaded('pdo_mysql') ? array_filter([
                PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA => env('MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA'),
            ]) : [],
        ],
```

If you want to check you version

```
php artisan -v
```

May be error will happens by artisan. For now this is my artisan from Laravel Framework 7.30.4 and php 7.2 look it if you didn't find anything suspecious, didn't change your artisan file take a copy oe backup. And soon as possible show me your error log.

```html
#!/usr/bin/env php
<?php

define('LARAVEL_START', microtime(true));

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Register The Auto Loader
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Composer provides a convenient, automatically generated class loader
| for our application. We just need to utilize it! We'll require it
| into the script here so that we do not have to worry about the
| loading of any our classes "manually". Feels great to relax.
|
*/

require __DIR__.'/vendor/autoload.php';

$app = require_once __DIR__.'/bootstrap/app.php';

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Run The Artisan Application
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| When we run the console application, the current CLI command will be
| executed in this console and the response sent back to a terminal
| or another output device for the developers. Here goes nothing!
|
*/

$kernel = $app->make(Illuminate\Contracts\Console\Kernel::class);

$status = $kernel->handle(
    $input = new Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput,
    new Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput
);

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Shutdown The Application
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Once Artisan has finished running, we will fire off the shutdown events
| so that any final work may be done by the application before we shut
| down the process. This is the last thing to happen to the request.
|
*/

$kernel->terminate($input, $status);

exit($status);
```

Comment: If you solve your problem can you approve my answer to helps others

Comment: the database already exists in phpmyadmin, but its returning not foudn

Comment: of course go to storage->logs->laravel.log and post your error log here so i can check why laravel refuse to connect

Comment: did you change core file like this vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php:703 .. If you remember that unfortunetely you changed you core then you can tell us.

Comment: I found the issue, so my ~bash directory had the incorrect $PATH, I updated the $PATH and I was able to sort out the issue

Comment: @ThandoHlophe now can you approve my answer

Answer (score 0):

If you're on a MAC using MAMP, adding this to my `.env` file worked for me

`DB_SOCKET=/Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock`